# Why does Predicates.instanceOf returns false?

Tags: java, jackson, guava, instanceof, predicates

I have a

```
String s =
    {
      "code1" : {
        "price" : 100,
        "type" : null
      },
      "code2" : {
        "price" : 110,
        "type" : null
      }
    }
```

Then I do:

```
Object p = Mapper.readValue(s, Person.class);
```

So it executes the method annotated with `@JsonCreator` in `Person.class`:

```
@JsonCreator
static Person create(Map<String, Object> s) {
        s = Maps.filterValues(s, Predicates.instanceOf(Person.class));
        ...
    }
```

My problem is `s` is always empty. I checked and the values have a `price` and a `type`. But when I do `ps.get("code1").getClass()`, it gives me `LinkedHashMap`.

I don't understand what is happening... Do you have any clue?

This is my class `Person` (it's an inner class):

```
public static class Person{

        private int price;
        private String type;
        public Person(int price) {
            this.price = price;
        }
        public int getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is a chicken and egg problem. You are literally writing the creator for the Person class. How would expect that the Object values in the Map could be Person instances yet?

Comment: @jordaniac89 Huh? That's not what that statement means at all.

Comment: Could you please provide the defenition of class Person

Comment: @rmlan: that's why the filter is here for. In this particular case, I have Person instances, but it doesn't work...

Comment: No, you don't. You are _creating_ person instances. As such, your Object instances are still Maps. `ps.get("code1").get("price");` will return an Integer with the value of 100.

Comment: Please also provide how did you define you Mapper

Comment: @eGoLai: it's just  `new ObjectMapper()`

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire It's Google Guava: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava

Comment: I'm rather familiar with Guava (the question was even tagged). I actually meant the other library, the one with `@JsonCreator` and `ObjectMapper`. Is it Jackson or another fancy library? This might explain some things.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire: it's Jackson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are deserializing json `String` to `Object` and you will always have `LinkedHashMap` there, because `java.lang.Object` doesn't have any custom field.

Just try a different way:

```
  public  class Demo {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            String s = "{" +
                    "  \"code1\" : {" +
                    "    \"price\" : 100," +
                    "    \"type\" : null" +
                    "  }," +
                    "  \"code3\" : {" +
                    "    \"somethingElsse\" : false," +
                    "    \"otherType\" : 1" +
                    "  }," +
                    "  \"code2\" : {" +
                    "    \"price\" : 110," +
                    "    \"type\" : null" +
                    "  }" +
                    "}";


            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            Map<String, Person> mapPerson = mapper.readValue(s, MapPerson.class);

            Map<String, Person> filteredMap = Maps.filterValues(mapPerson, new Predicate<Person>() {
                @Override
                public boolean apply(Person person) {
                    return person.isNotEmpty();
                }
            });

            System.out.println(filteredMap);


        }

        public static class MapPerson extends HashMap<String, Person> {}

        public static class Person{

            private int price;
            private String type;

            public Person() {
            }

            public boolean isNotEmpty() {
                return !(0 == price && null ==type);
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "Person{" +
                        "price=" + price +
                        ", type='" + type + '\'' +
                        '}';
            }

            public int getPrice() {
                return price;
            }

            public void setPrice(int price) {
                this.price = price;
            }

            public String getType() {
                return type;
            }

            public void setType(String type) {
                this.type = type;
            }
        }
    }
```

When you configure your objec mapper with `configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)` it will just add an empty instance of Person to your map instead of throwing an exception.
So you should also define a method that will answer if an instance of Person is empty and then filter your map using it.

If you use java 8 you can have a less code when you filter the map:

```
Map<String, Person> filteredMap = Maps.filterValues(mapPerson, Person::isNotEmpty);
```

BTW, it will work wine even you have some extra fields inside key values fro you JSON:

```
 {
      "code1" : {
        "price" : 100,
        "type" : null,
        "uselessExtraField": "Hi Stack"
      },
      "code2" : {
        "price" : 110,
        "type" : null,
        "anotherAccidentalField": "What?"
      }
    }
```

You will have the same result as if that fields never existed.

Comment: Ok I see why I always have `LinkedHashMap`... Thanks!